# How to upgrade Samsung galaxy A5 to lollipop without using Kies?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, updates, samsung, device-firmware

I'm on Manjaro Linux can't use Kies, I tried it in virtualbox, didn't work as expected. I live in Lebanon, so no A&T version or anything like that, I need standard firmware.

I have galaxy A5, current version 4.4.4, I want to upgrade to lollipop. Isn't available from settings > software update. I want to download it and do it manually, my device isn't rooted yet, will root it soon.

- Model Number: SM-A500H

Found one [here, first one](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-A500H/), but I don't know if I can trust the source and it's Uzbekistan, I don't know if I should use it.Note that Kies in virtualbox detected some firmware, I just couldn't install it, so there is a firmware out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded [this](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/download/51317/A500HXXU1BOG4_A500HODD1BOG4_BNG/) and flashed it using odin (windows running in virtualbox) and it worked. Using the Uzbekistan firmware should work too, from my own experience. But don't root it using **CF-Auto-Root** it will break your phone and you'll have to flash it again.